# Using hyphen or underscore as word separator for files under Linux

Tags: c++, linux, naming-conventions, filenames

I get always confused when I have to give a new name for a new data or executable file under linux, to use underscore or the dash to separate words in the name.

My question: Are there any standard or guide to follow to know when to use this or that?

Comment: About the only rules are that filenames (not pathnames) cannot contain `/` or the null character and must be no longer 255 characters. Good luck, however, trying to delete a file whose name is `" "` or `"-f *\n"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ ls /usr/bin/*_* | wc -l
120
$ ls /usr/bin/*-* | wc -l
717
```

Some files are actually duplicated in both lists: `x86_64-linux-gnu-cpp`, but you probably get the idea that there are more dashes that underscores. Additionally there are files where there is no separation whatsoever as in `atktopbm`, `bdftruncate`... not really standard it seems.